# CSS layout difficulties, site behaves in chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, positioning

I am having cross browser problems with this site, can someone explain to me why it's not working in Firefox but does in google chrome please?

When an image is clicked, the text is not positioned correctly in Firefox

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2306276/problem/index.html

I think it has something to do with

```
display: table;
```

but I do not know why.

thanks

Comment: Please post some relevant code here and describe *what* exactly is not working

Comment: I have posted the site, you can use firebug to see the code. I have described the problem, the "text is not positioned correctly" what more do you want? It is further down and to the left, and sometimes to the right than it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these bits of your CSS:

```
div.container {
    height: 215px;
    line-height: 215px;
    width: 215px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It's normally safer to avoid `display: table-*` where possible.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much for this @Eric, works perfectly. I was using "display: table" to "shrink-wrap" the div, and I had tried using "display: inline-block;" but that had caused an alignment issue. many thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10209

It's also fixed in Firefox nightlies; the fix will ship in Firefox 10.

Answer (score -1):

try to set "position:relative" it may work